# apache ignite transaction in thick client

Tags: .net-core, ignite

I have a code that use locking and it worked fine whn I used think client. After I switch the code to use thick client I get the following exception:

> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction [cacheNames=SQL_MYAPP_MODELS_COUNTERS, operation=dynamicStartCache] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction [cacheNames=SQL_MYAPP_MODELS_COUNTERS, operation=dynamicStartCache]
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformUtils.unwrapQueryException(PlatformUtils.java:520)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.runFieldsQuery(PlatformCache.java:1409)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutObject(PlatformCache.java:1000)
> [... truncated...]

I am not sure what it means by "start/stop cache." The transaction block only contains logics to create the `SqlFieldsQuery()` then call `cache.Query()` (which is where the code breaks)

Why and how can I use transaction with thick client?

Comment: The exception says that `SQL_MYAPP_MODELS_COUNTERS` cache is being created within a transaction. Does the SQL query have `CREATE TABLE` in it?

Comment: I am using sql api to create all my tables on application start. I use `GetOrCreateCache()` api to create the cache outside the transaction scope. Even when I use just  `GetCache()` I still get the same issue. So I don't quite get why it is trying to create a cache.e

Answer (score 1):

It turns out "start/stop" means the cache is first accessed or something. So I wrote a query outside my transaction using-block to access the cache and that seems to have solved it.